# Rails Validation - Validate Value returned from Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model called `Event` and another called `Project`. I am trying to set some validation on creation of the `Event` such that firstly a `project_id` value must be supplied (this already works) and then to check that that project's `schedule_mode` value is not `'free'`. However, I am struggling to **firstly** pass the `project_id` value which will be provided as a parameter and **secondly**, even if I hardcode that in temporarily, it then complains that `'undefined method`free''`, which is the`schedule_mode` returned. Where am I going wrong?

```
validates Project.find(:project_id).schedule_mode, exclusion: { in: %w(free) }
```

Comment: Can you post your `Project` and `Event` models?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that, `Event` *belongs_to* `Project`, you can add a custom validator in your `Event` model:

```
# app/model/event.rb
validate :schedule_mode

private

def schedule_mode
  if project.schedule_mode == 'free'
    errors.add(:schedule_mode, "value can't be free")
  end
end
```